# Ruby.h no such file or directory parser.o Error

Tags: ruby

Using Rails 3.1 and a new app, when go to  run `bundle install` I got the following errors

```
Installing json<1.7.3> with native extensions
Error: Failed to build gem native extension.
Creating Makefile
generating parser-i386-mingw32.def
compiling parser.c
In file included from parser.rl:1:0:../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:6:18: fatal error: ruby.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1
```

I have successfully installed DevKit and change the `$PATH` like below:

```
C:\Users\peter\Downloads\make-3.81-bin\bin;
C:\Users\peter\Working\Ruby-devKit\mingw\bin;
C:\Users\peter\Working\Ruby-devKit;
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.8-Q16;
C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Ruby\bin;
```

Comment: Whitespaces are in some cases the start of strange things ;). Perhaps rearangement or escaping does help?

Comment: I noticed you're using Windows. Did you use the RailsInstaller, or just the RubyInstaller and the DevKit?

Comment: do you have the file ruby.h anywhere? what if you do a manual $ gem install json?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the ruby development kit because Windows is looking for the source code to Ruby based on the error missing Ruby.h